# Magento2.3.5: How to remove index.php and theme id from url?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

my website homepage is accessible with index.php and theme ID which is as below

**https://baseurl/index.php**

**https://baseurl/porto_home_26**

how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engine Optimisation -> Web Server Rewrites : YES.**

You should make sure that your **Secure** and **Unsecure** base urls end with **"/"**.

Now edit your **.htaccess** of magento root folder and add below code

````
RewriteBase /{magento directory}/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /{magento directory}/index.php [L]```
````

Comment: what about theme_id, how to remove access from theme id

Answer (score 0):

you should add url-rewrite to your .htaccess or nginx rule. I think it is the fastest way. Define there redirect rule and issue is closed :)